# get particular value by key from Hashmap in velocity template

Tags: java, velocity, velocity-template-language

i have a java code like below

```
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    VelocityEngine engine = new VelocityEngine();
    engine.init();

    Template template = engine.getTemplate("userinfo.vm");

    VelocityContext vc = new VelocityContext();

    Map<String, Object> jsonResponse = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    jsonResponse.put("44", "United Kingdom");
    jsonResponse.put("33", "France");
    jsonResponse.put("49", null);

    vc.put("userList", jsonResponse);
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    template.merge(vc, writer);

    System.out.println(writer);
}
```

in .vm file

```
#foreach ($mapEntry in $userList.entrySet())
$!{mapEntry.get("44")}
#end
```

Here i am trying to get particular value using above code, but its not giving expected output

My expected output is

```
 United Kingdom
```

Comment: And the actual output is ?

Comment: mapEntry is... a map entry. Is there any get() method expecting a key in Map.Entry? Why are you iterating on the map entries if all you need is a specific value? How would you get that specific value in Java code?

Comment: I don't use Velocity, but why iterate over the `entrySet` when you only want a single value directly from the Map?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this code to iterate through your map values. It is almost the same as yours however pay attention to: `$userList.keySet()` instead of `$userList.entrySet()` and `$!{userList.get($mapKey )}` instead of `$!{mapEntry.get("44")}`

```
#foreach($mapKey in $userList.keySet())
    $!{userList.get($mapKey )}
#end
```

If you want just to access a specific value of your map try this:

```
$!{userList.get("44")}
```

Comment: Thanks!. i have one more query if i want to put got value from map to another map in .vm. Its showing extra line of code along with output. Here is my code in .vm #set ($myMap = {})
$myMap.put('Country', $!{userList.get("44")})
$myMap.get('Country')  i want only United Kingdom as output. What i am doing wrong

Comment: Sorry I cannot clearly understand what you are asking, can you also post the actual output? (Although it does not format well in the comments section, it would be better to ask a new question)

Answer (score 0):

Per https://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/user-guide.html#set:

> You could access the first element above using
>   `$monkey.Map.get("banana")` to return a String 'good', or even
>   `$monkey.Map.banana` to return the same value.

Per https://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/user-guide.html#index-notation

`$foo["bar"]   ## Passing a string where $foo may be a Map`